# "Side to Side" meaning

Tags: meaning

Everyone heard Ariana's Side to Side. Yeah? I've been listening it since it was released, but the meaning of the title, i didn't get. Can someone please clarify the title.

My thoughts:

Got me walking side to side: Hey boy, take me with you, we will scrounge the beauty and thrill, we will walk together facing the same way.

I also thought it could be replaced with side by side...isn't it? Please Clear!

Comment: Hey! Thanks for joining ELU!  While we welcome most questions involving English, the design of StackExchange interfaces poorly with opinion-oriented questions, and so they're off-topic generally.  Instead, we skew more towards the "mechanical" side of linguistics, operating on the syntactic, morphological, phonological, orthographic, and etymological levels, etc. The nuts-and-bolts of English as it were.  Questions of meaning (semantics, pragmatics) are also accepted, but questions of interpretation ( litcrit, poetry, lyrics) are too far towards "subjective" end of the spectrum for the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the primary meaning of "side to side" (as an adverbial) is "side by side".  [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/side_to_side) lists this meaning first for "side to side" as an adverb:

> Close together and facing in the same direction; with the sides touching or close together; = side by side

A second definition, as well as the only definition for "side to side" as an adjective, is "designating movement from one side to the other ...".

Comment: Note that you quote from ODO, not OED. You need to add links yourself in future. Also, this is general reference.